# How to find Browser close [X] event (in javascript/code behind). It should support Cross browser

Tags: events, browser, cross-browser

Can you please explain, how to fire browser closing event (IE,FF,Chrome,Opera and Safari)? And I would like to redirects to another page which is LogOut.aspx. In that page I would like to kill the session and store the logout time in database table.

Answer (score 0):

Took a while, but created a solution in jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).unload(function(){
            window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_blank");
        });
    });
```

When the window is closed, it will create a new tab with the url provided, you can replace
it with your logout page.

Comment: Hi Drake, Thanks for your post, I have some queries as follows, Please resolve ...unload event fires event if transfers from one page to another page,post back events and etc. But I need to know whether its unloading by anyother event or explicitly closing the browser. by using the simple unload we cannot justify right this is the browser close.